# Resize Picture Taken With createScaledBitmap

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-bitmap

I am trying to take a picture with the max camera size and then scale it to 1080x1776, with a quality of 80% and saving the bitmap as .jpeg. Even though I am pretty sure that I am rotating the matrix in the wrong way, since the only way to get 1080x1776 working is to set the parameters the other way around in createScaledBitmap, this code works with my Nexus 5.

When I tried the same code on a One Plus, I got a really low resolution quality. I don't understand why since the code works on a Nexus 5, which has similar specs, it shouldn't be working for the one plus. On the One Plus the picture is scaling in the right way 1080x1776, but the quality is bad.

Does anyone know why? Same code, new phones, different results? I have also tried the code on a Nexus 7 and still I do have bad pictures. Why would this code work on my nexus 5?

```
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

   Bitmap imageScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 1776, 1080, true);

    // Override Android default landscape orientation and save portrait
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
    {
        float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
        matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

        matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);

    }

    matrix.postRotate(90);

    Bitmap rotatedScaledImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageScaled, 0,
            0, imageScaled.getWidth(), imageScaled.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    rotatedScaledImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);
```